# Vertical gap on top of the page

Tags: luatex, overleaf

There is a vertical gap on the top due to that I think my content of that page shifts to another page. I have tried researching the solution on the net. But none worked for me. Can you please help me?

Thank you.

Below are the code and images of PDF.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{fancybox}

\usepackage{float}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\graphicspath{ {images/} }

\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Times New Roman}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\linespread{1.5}

\begin{document}


\begin{center}
    
    \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
        \draw[black,line width=2pt] ([xshift=-1.5cm,yshift=-1.5cm]current page.north east)
        coordinate (A)--([xshift=1.5cm,yshift=-1.5cm]current page.north west)
        coordinate(B)--([xshift=1.5cm,yshift=1.5cm]current page.south west)
        coordinate (C)--([xshift=-1.5cm,yshift=1.5cm]current page.south east)
        coordinate(D)--cycle;
    \end{tikzpicture}

    \thispagestyle{empty}
    Title
    
    Subtitle
    \begin{figure}[h]
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=1\textwidth]{logo.jpg}
    \end{figure}
    
    {\large \textbf{Project Name}} \\
    
    {\normalsize On} \\
    
    {\large \textbf{Project Title}} \\
    \textit{subtext} \\
    {\large \textbf{Degree}} \\
    {\normalsize \textbf{In}} \\
    {\large \textbf{Degree Title}} \\
    {\normalsize \textbf{Submitted by}} \\
    {\normalsize Name} \\
    {\normalsize \textbf{Under}} \\
    Name \\
    {\normalsize \textbf{Under}} \\
    Name \\
    SCHOOL name \\
    Address. \\
    Year
\end{center}

\newpage
Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.

\end{document}
```

Page 1:

[image: Page 1]

Page 2:

[image: Page 2]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! TeX does not break the `tikzpicture` for the frame across pages. What you see is an artefact of your pdf viewer. Page 2 is not the second page of the document, but the second screen of the viewer, probably after pressing page down. Check the settings of the pdf viewer. Usually you can tell it to display the contents of the pdf file page-wise. In my pdf viewer, I have to uncheck "continuous" and to select "fit page".

Comment: If you want to see the borders and margins of LaTeX, add the line `\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}` to the preamble of your document. It will mark the areas for header, footer, main text, and margin notes. Then you can judge whether your text introduces any additional space.

Comment: @gernot in overleaf, in the preview slide, the PDF contains 2 pages, actually 3 if we count the lorem ipsum new page. The second page is empty at bottom after showing the shifted content. And when I use the `\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}`, the text pushes upward.

Comment: When replacing your elephant with some dummy image, I also get three pages. The second page contains stuff that doesn't fit on the first page. You can either compress the contents by reducing the size of the image or reduce the number of lines by not putting everything on a separate line, or reduce the gap between the lines. You can also enlarge the text area of the first page (or of the whole document); the package `geometry` allows you to adjust that. The bottomline is: You cannot fit more stuff on a page than the size of the text area allows you to.

Comment: Agreed. But as you can see, the first page has a large vertical gap, if we reduce it, the content which is shifted to the second page must come to the first page, if not all but few of them must come. But the expected behaviour is not matching.

Comment: Have you added the line `\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}`? In my copy of your sample document, the first page starts at the top of the text area, but flows to the next page, as the text area is too small for the stuff you want to put there.

Comment: The word `Title` doesn't really start at the top of the page body. It does if one replaces the `center` environment with `\centering` (not the same!) and removes the paragraph break after the `tikzpicture`: `\thispagestyle{empty} {\centering \begin{tikzpicture}...\end{tikzpicture}Title ... Year\par}`.

Comment: Thank you so much, guys. Your input was helpful.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it was answered in the comments.